# Comparing two list and getting result a list with some checks

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two list a and b I have to get result of two list one with elements which are in both and one in which elements of b which aren't present in a.I have to write the code in python.output and should look like this.

```
    a = ['product','shampoo','vivel','spark']
    b = ['random','product','shampoo','nothing']
    c = ['product','shampoo']
    d = ['random','nothing']
```

I need an efficient one as I have to do this some process many times
Thank you, please let me know if there is any unclarity.

Comment: What's your question? Note: "how do I do this assignment?" is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to perform this task consists of using `set` -

```
a = ['product','shampoo','vivel','spark']
b = ['random','product','shampoo','nothing']

c = list(set(a) & set(b))

d = list(set(b) - set(a))

print(c)

print(d)
```

Output -

```
['product', 'shampoo']
['nothing', 'random']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use set operations, since that is essentially what you're after.

```
>>> a = ['product','shampoo','vivel','spark']
>>> b = ['random','product','shampoo','nothing']
```

The list `c` would be the result of a set `intersection`

```
>>> c = set(a).intersection(b)
>>> c
{'shampoo', 'product'}
```

The list `d` would be the result of a set `difference` of `a` from `b`.

```
>>> d = set(b).difference(a)
>>> d
{'random', 'nothing'}
```

There are operators for sets that perform these operations as well

```
>>> set(a) & set(b)
{'shampoo', 'product'}
>>> set(b) - set(a)
{'random', 'nothing'}
```